# How do you replace subitem text with image & only show image in a listview?

Tags: c#, listview

I have the need for some help again. I have managed to get just about to the end with it but I am having a issue

Task: In a listview I have rows and there is certain columns that show either true or false. I want to replace the true and false text with a image to represent them I have that part done but the image is showing however the text of either true or false is still showing and nothing I try will allow me to remove them without causing other issue.

I will provide a screenshot as well as the code for the listview1_DrawSubItem

[image: Picture of what it does]

Here is the code from the Draw SubItem

```
 private void listView1_DrawSubItem(object sender, DrawListViewSubItemEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.Header == this.columnHeader9)
        {



            if (e.Item.SubItems[8].Text == "True")
            {
                var imageRect = new Rectangle(e.Bounds.X, e.Bounds.Y, e.Bounds.Height, e.Bounds.Height);
                e.Graphics.DrawImage(imageList.Images[8], imageRect);
                                }

            if (e.Item.SubItems[8].Text == "False")
            {
                var imageRect = new Rectangle(e.Bounds.X, e.Bounds.Y, e.Bounds.Height, e.Bounds.Height);
                e.Graphics.DrawImage(imageList.Images[7], imageRect);
            }




        }
        if (e.Header == this.columnHeader11)
        {
            if (e.Item.SubItems[9].Text == "True")
            {
                var imageRect = new Rectangle(e.Bounds.X, e.Bounds.Y, e.Bounds.Height, e.Bounds.Height);
                e.Graphics.DrawImage(imageList.Images[7], imageRect);
                                 }

            if (e.Item.SubItems[9].Text == "False")
            {
                var imageRect = new Rectangle(e.Bounds.X, e.Bounds.Y, e.Bounds.Height, e.Bounds.Height);
                e.Graphics.DrawImage(imageList.Images[8], imageRect);
                                }
                         }
        if (e.Header == this.columnHeader13)
        {
            if (e.Item.SubItems[11].Text == "True")
            {
                var imageRect = new Rectangle(e.Bounds.X, e.Bounds.Y, e.Bounds.Height, e.Bounds.Height);
                e.Graphics.DrawImage(imageList.Images[7], imageRect);
                                 }
            if (e.Item.SubItems[11].Text == "False")
            {
                var imageRect = new Rectangle(e.Bounds.X, e.Bounds.Y, e.Bounds.Height, e.Bounds.Height);
                e.Graphics.DrawImage(imageList.Images[8], imageRect);
                                 }
                       }
        if (e.Header == this.columnHeader14)
        {
            if (e.Item.SubItems[12].Text == "True")
            {
                var imageRect = new Rectangle(e.Bounds.X, e.Bounds.Y, e.Bounds.Height, e.Bounds.Height);
                e.Graphics.DrawImage(imageList.Images[7], imageRect);
                                }
            if (e.Item.SubItems[12].Text == "False")
            {
                var imageRect = new Rectangle(e.Bounds.X, e.Bounds.Y, e.Bounds.Height, e.Bounds.Height);
                e.Graphics.DrawImage(imageList.Images[8], imageRect);
                                }
                       }

        if (e.Header == this.columnHeader20)
        {
            if (e.Item.SubItems[19].Text == "True")
            {
                var imageRect = new Rectangle(e.Bounds.X, e.Bounds.Y, e.Bounds.Height, e.Bounds.Height);
                e.Graphics.DrawImage(imageList.Images[7], imageRect);
                                }
            if (e.Item.SubItems[19].Text == "False")
            {
                var imageRect = new Rectangle(e.Bounds.X, e.Bounds.Y, e.Bounds.Height, e.Bounds.Height);
                e.Graphics.DrawImage(imageList.Images[8], imageRect);
                                }
                         }
        e.DrawText();
    }
```

I hope someone can help me get this right as its all done but this one issue.

Comment: get rid of `e.DrawText();` for those columns if I understand correctly.  Much easier to do with a DataGridView, by the way.

Comment: When I do that there is nothing in the listview list but the images. Yes I know that now. but there is a lot to be done to change it over

Comment: Is that what you want?  the image instead of True/False?

Comment: Right ! just for these columns though the text in the other columns are fine

Comment: You are drawing much more than you need - rather than drawing ALL the  subitems, with absolute references (`e.Item.SubItems[9]`), draw the one that Windows is asking you to draw: `e.ColumnIndex`.   Then only `DrawText()` when ``e.ColumnIndex`` is < 5 or the first image-only column.

Comment: I just did this here
  if (e.Header != this.columnHeader9)
            {
                e.DrawText();
            } 
and it worked buyt when I did it for the others it came back

Comment: The event is named `DrawSubItem`. Windows needs only one (1) drawn, the one passed to you in `DrawListViewSubItemEventArgs e`.  Rewrite your code to use `e.ColumnIndex`  and conditionally print the text

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have got it. I added this

```
    if (e.Header != this.columnHeader9 &
     e.Header != this.columnHeader11 &  e.Header != this.columnHeader13
     & e.Header != this.columnHeader14 & e.Header != this.columnHeader20)
        {
            e.DrawText();
        }
```

and it works. 
It draws the text on all the columns but the ones I defined above.

Thanks for your help`